# need advice for jquery plugin with UI embedded

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I need to write a jQuery plugin with some UI as html. It is tedious to code a bunch of `.html()` calls into it. Is there a better way to handle this? Thanks

Comment: It's unfortunately a little difficult to say without knowing a little more about why it's becoming tedious? Perhaps some code samples would help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure of what you mean by `.html()` call's so I will assume you have a plugin that adds/edits the DOM a lot. There really isn't a better way using jQuery to manage the DOM then the built in functions, some of the functions are better then others (like it is faster to update existing DOM then to add new DOM) and stuff like that. If you really worry about performance it is faster to do the following

```
jQuery(document.createElement("a"));
```

then it would be to do

```
jQuery("a");
```

And string mode is faster then a bunch of options

```
jQuery("<a id='cheese' rel='stuff'><span></span><i></i></a>");
```

is faster then

```
jQuery("<a>", {id: "cheese", rel: "stuff"}).append("<span>").append("<i>");
```

My suggestion would be to just use the `jQuery.html()` and try and make sure your selectors are as good as you can get them (id's over classes, closes element then transition down, remove unneeded steps, etc). If you are really concerned you can use native javascript DOM creation methods and map it to jQuery.